# JavaScript / Node.js: function returning another function based on parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

When the Node.js application loads, many different things are set up, and e.g. `requires.has('message', 'text')` is called. This should set up a function that checks if the passed data object contains `message.text`.

The following code registers an handler (The syntax is bot.register(callback, requirements)).

```
bot.register(irrelevant, [requires.has('message', 'text')]);
```

When a http request comes in, all requirements are executed: So, a callback must be generated from `requires.has('message', 'text')`.

So, in short:

```
requires.has('message', 'text')
```

must return

```
{
  callable: function(data) { // check if data has nodes message and text }
}
```

Sorry if that explanation sounds confusing, I hope you know what I mean.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is a function that returns another function as an object key.

```
requires.has = function(parameters) {
  return {
    callable: function (data) {
      // your implementation, has access to parameters & data variables
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Oh, wait, it really does have access to upper variables? If that works, great. Let me just try it...

Comment: Sure, JS variables have access to every variable defined before in upper scopes. I’d recommend for you to read You Don’t Know JS (at least the part about scopes & closures) – don’t be offensed by the name, it’s actually a great book and available for free on GitHub: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures

Comment: Yeah, I know... That was still kinda confusing to me as the 'callable' function itself is called from somewhere completely else. And it doesn't necessarily make sense to me that that code in there does also have access to the outer variables... If you know what I mean. Thank you!